# Calculate Weights of a Column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, calculated-columns, weighted

this is a basic quesiton and easy to do in excel but have not an idea in python and every example online uses groupby with multiple names in the name column. So, all I need is a row value of weights from a single column. Suppose I have data that looks like this:

```
        name    value
0       A       45
1       B       76
2       C       320
3       D       210
```

The answer should look like this:

```
0      name     value  weights
1      A        45     0.069124
2      B        76     0.116743
3      C        320    0.491551
4      D        210    0.322581
```

thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat `sum` per groups, so possible divide original column:

```
print (df.groupby('name')['value'].transform('sum'))
0    651
1    651
2    651
3    651
Name: value, dtype: int64

df['weights'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby('name')['value'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
  name  value   weights
0    A     45  0.069124
1    A     76  0.116743
2    A    320  0.491551
3    A    210  0.322581
```

EDIT:

```
df['weights'] = df['value'].div(df['value'].sum())
print (df)
  name  value   weights
0    A     45  0.069124
1    B     76  0.116743
2    C    320  0.491551
3    D    210  0.322581
```

Comment: sorry, my data  in the 'name' column has different names for each row - example is not correct. can you take a look after the edits?

Comment: @user2100039 - So need divide sum of all column by column like in `EDIT` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also groupby 'name' and then apply a function that divides each value by its group sum:

```
df['weights'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

Output:

```
  name  value   weights
0    A     45  0.069124
1    A     76  0.116743
2    A    320  0.491551
3    A    210  0.322581
```

For new data:

```
df['weights'] = df['value'] / df['value'].sum()

  name  value   weights
0    A     45  0.069124
1    B     76  0.116743
2    C    320  0.491551
3    D    210  0.322581
```